# How to make Android Studio build fail on lint errors

Tags: android-studio, android-lint

Is it possible to make Android Studio build fail on lint check errors ?
I have problems with ImageViews when I convert icon from .png to vector drawable .xml
Sometimes I forgot to change
`android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"`
to
`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_minus"`
and the app crashes on older OS devices.

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's a lint check for that you can change the severity to `FATAL` and then when building the release version of your APK it should fail.

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    fatal 'MY_LINT_CHECK_ID'
  }
}
```

Also you can execute the Gradle `lint` task which will fail. If you also want warnings to let your build fail you can use this.

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    warningsAsErrors true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below code inside `android` block in module/app level `build.gradle` file

For `build.gradle`

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all {
        // Example lint task, your verification task can be anything
        def lintTask = tasks["lint${name.capitalize()}"]
        assembleProvider.get().dependsOn(lintTask/*, detekt*/) // add list of all the tasks which should fail the build
    }
}
```

For `build.gradle.kts`(Kotlin DSL)

```kotlin
android {
    applicationVariants.all {
        // Example lint task, your verification task can be anything
        val lintTask = tasks["lint${name.capitalize()}"]
        assembleProvider.get().dependsOn.addAll(listOf(lintTask/*, tasks["detekt"]*/))  // add list of all the tasks which should fail the build
    }
}
```

Above code makes the build assemble task which run when we run build app or run app, depends on the listed verification tasks and hence fails it when those tasks fails

Make sure your verification tasks(in our case `lint` task) are set to fail the build when they are run and there are some issues found in them. All verification tasks has their own flags to enable this behaviour.

For lint you can enable the build failure on warning as below(`build.gradle.kts` for Kotlin DSL)

```kotlin
android {
    lint {
        isWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
```